# Json schema provides a default for an object but not for its properties

Tags: jsonschema, default-value

I have a property somewhere in my JSON schema that is of type "object" and has a default value - an object with its properties and their values. Inside the object schema I have the properties listed and their types specified - but no defaults for them. The question is - in what will this property result if only one of the values is provided but non of the rest? Will they default to what they would if noting was provided?

```
"autoStart": {
            "type": "object",
            "default":{
                "foo": true,
                "bar": 3
            },
            "properties":{
                "foo": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "bar": {
                    "type": "number"
                }
            }
        }
```

If the provided json is

```
"autoStart": {
  "foo": false
}
```

what will happen to the "bar"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `default` *do*? Nothing according to the specification

`default` is an annotation keyword. An annotation is to provide information to an implementation or application so they can define their own additional behaviour. This means any behaviour which does ANYTHING with `default` is implementation or application specific.

Let's look at what the spec says...

> There are no restrictions placed on the value of this keyword.
> When    multiple occurrences of this keyword are applicable to a
> single sub-instance, implementations SHOULD remove duplicates.
>
> This keyword can be used to supply a default JSON value associated
> with a particular schema.  It is RECOMMENDED that a default value be
> valid against the associated schema.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-10.2

Besides annotation collection and return, there's nothing an implementation should be expected to DO with an annotation keyword, apart from that which it defines in its own documentation.